# Help with remote debugging under linux

Tags: windows, linux, debugging, opengl

At present we are developing a graphic app on a linux box using opengl.  We have had a bit of trouble getting a decent debugger working.  At present we use GDB via a ssh connection, but that is a tad painful.  Next we have tried running DDD on the target platform, but we run out of space on screen.  Next we have tried running an xserver via cygwin on windows and doing an "export DISPLAY=RemoteHost:0.0" on the linux box.  In this situation DDD will run on the windows box, but when we boot the app it also wants to pipe its output to the windows box.

What we really want to do is have DDD output on our windows box, and the output of the main app on the linux box.

I am not a x11 guru and I would love some help in this area.

Cheers

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While logged in into the linux box:

```
DISPLAY=windows-box:0 ddd /path/to/app
```

`DDD` should now pop up on your windows box. If you run the app at that point, it will attempt to display on windows box as well, since the `DISPLAY` environment variable is inherited. You need to reset it:

```
(gdb) set env DISPLAY :0
(gdb) run
```

At that point, the app should display on the linux box, as desired.

Many applications accept `-display` command line argument. If yours does, an alternative is to do this:

```
(gdb) run -display :0
```

instead of resetting the `DISPLAY` environment variable.